# how to rewrite Mongo client code using MongoDB driver instead

Tags: php, mongodb

**Background Information:**

I have a PHP script that parses a text file and uses it to insert data into a mongo database.  I'm moving away from the old Mongo PHP driver to use the MongoDB\Driver classes instead (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php)

**Problem**

There's one section of code that I'm trying to rewrite using the new classes but I can't seem to get it working - aka its not writing data to the database... and I don't know how to find the error either.

**Old Code:**

This is the old code:

```
 //database variables
 $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");

 $db = "locations";
 function update_location_status($location)
 {
    global $m, $db;
    $collection = $db->locations;
    echo "<pre>".json_encode($status)."</pre>";

    try {
        $cursor = $collection->update(array('domain'=>$status['domain']) , array('$set'=>$status), array('upsert'=>true) ); 
        echo "Successfully upserted location status record for ". $location['domain'] ." into database...<BR>";
        return true;        
    } catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
        var_dump($cursor);
        return false;
    }
```

**New Code**

```
    $m = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
    function update_location_status($location)
    {
    global $m;
    echo "<pre>".json_encode($status)."</pre>";
    $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
    $bulk->update(
        [array('domain'=>$status['domain'])],
        [array('domain'=>$status)],
        ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => true]
    );

    try{
        $writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);
        $result = $m->executeBulkWrite('db.locations', $bulk, $writeConcern);
        if($result->getInsertedCount()){
            return true;
        }else{
            echo "<font color=red><pre>";
            var_dump($result->getWriteErrors());
            echo "</pre></font>";

            return false;
        }
    } catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
        var_dump($result);
        return false;
    }
```

**Results**

My attempt to dump the error message using `getWriteErrors` returns an empty array:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

So I've updated the code and it's creating data, but it looks different from the previous / old code. 
This is what the data from the old code looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584586312a0d63c2e21eee12"), 
    "bbn" : "133", 
    "customized" : true, 
    "nep" : "812", 
    "pdate" : ISODate("2017-02-05T06:44:41Z"), 
    "domain" : "test.mydomain", "status" : false, "t_name" : "agcab", "type" : "current_status" 
}
```

And with this code:

```
global $m, $db;
echo "<pre>".json_encode($status)."</pre>";
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->update(
    ['domain'=>$status['domain']],
    ['$set'=>['domain'=>$status]],
    ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => true]
);
```

the data ends up looking like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5910da5d99077b6b4887582f"), 
    "domain" : { 
        "bbn" : "133", 
        "nep" : "812", 
        "type" : "current_status", 
        "pdate" : ISODate("1970-01-18T07:00:12.882Z"), 
        "status" : false, 
        "domain" : "test.mydomain", 
        "tenant_name" : "agcab", 
        "customized" : true 
    } 
}
```

I don't want it nested under another "domain" array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your code to below.

```
 $bulk->update(
     ['domain'=>$status['domain']],
     ['$set'=>$status],
     ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => true]
 );

$result = $m->executeBulkWrite(dbname.collectionname, $bulk, $writeConcern);
```

Comment: I had to just tweak your code to change "['$set'=>['domain' =>$status]]," to just be "['$set'=>$status],"